# Is Observable what I should be using to detect a value being set?

Tags: angular, observable

On a project where we have a dataSet[].
And in the project there is a call that looks for a entry in the dataSet[]. The issue I'm seeing is that the existing code loops through every item in the dataSet[]. So if there are 500 or 5000 then it loops that many times even thought the record(s) may have already been found.

I'm new to this and so from what I'm reading it seems like somehow the dataSet[] should be some kind of observable where I could create a function that would listen for that to be set and then create a map. The map would allow us to do a simple get('key') and not do thousands of loops on every item being searched.

All examples of observable information that I have come across deals with http calls and subscribe.

So

1. Am I correct that I need to make this an Observable?
2. If so, how exactly do I go about taking the dataSet[] which is set via

   this.dataSet = [...resultData.results]

and make it as an observable in order for me to create a dataSetMap = [key, value]?

I'm thinking that in the function that gets the results results => {...}
I would create the observable inside of that did something like this

```
 myQueryService.getData.subscribe(
    (data:any) => {
      dataSet = data.results;

      const myObservable = new Observable(dataSet => {
        setTimeout(() => {
          dataSetMap.set(key, value);
        }, 500);
      });
  })
```

Answer (score 1):

From what i read it seems like what you want to do is notify anybody who is interested in the dataset about a new entry?
In this case i think the simplest approach is to create a Subject on which you emit a new value whenever you insert something.

So create a Subject at your service level together with your map and every time you call

```
dataSetMap.set(key, value)
```

you also call

```
mySubject.next([key, value])
```

Probably you can make this prettier using a class instead of an array as notification type.
You could also wrap the map and the subject together into your own class and provide a map like interface and only expose an observable instead of the subject via `my subject.asObservable()`

Somebody who is interesed in new entries in dataset would then subscribe like that:

```
 mySubject.subscribe((newEntry: [any, any]) => {
    const key = newEntry[0];
    const value = newEntry[1];
    // Do something
 })
```

You could also only push the key into the subject and access the value from the map in the subscribe block

95% of the time using existing rxjs classes is easier then writing your own observable.

However if you ever want to create your own observable you can do this via

```
const myObs = Observable.create((observer) => {
   /* In here is some code that will get executed every time some subscribe
      to it and you pass values to the subscribe via observer.next(val)
   */
})
```

Comment: I'll read up on what you have outlined and see if I can get this to work. Thank you for taking the time to assist.